# Unstable numerical solution of ODEs and PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, stability-in-odes

Choosing the right step size for a stiff ODE or a non-linear ODE and PDEs is an important factor. While studying a paper on choosing appropriate step size in numerically solving ODE, I questioned: What is the mathematical criteria to numerically determine when the solution has become unstable?

Comment: You can compute the Jacobian, then compute the relation between min and max eigenvalues. Search Gear's or Butcher's books.

Comment: Any books in particular? The authors complete name would be very helpful. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Shampine, L. F.; Gear, C. W. (1979), "A user's view of solving stiff ordinary differential equations", SIAM Review, 21 (1): 1–17.